# Amazon cloudfront IP resolution by client

Tags: javascript, dns

I have a webapp that uses a lot of images which are cached through CloudFront. Some users complain that the load time is excruciatingly slow, So I want to build a diagnostic page on the site that will do a speed test by loading a few images and reporting the time. I also want to report the users IP address (which I can easily get from php when they load the page), but I also want to show the IP address that they are getting for the cloudfront server.

I know that if I run:

```
dig subdomain.cloudfront.net
```

I get several IP addresses. If an app (browser, QT app, mobile app) is running simultaneous connections to subdomain.cloudfront.net, does it always use the first IP first and use the others only if it fails?

And is there any way from within the browser that I can get these IP addresses as they are from the client users system? It's my understanding that they will get a different list of IPs based on their IP address.

If this is not possible from within the browser, is there any type of request that I could send to the cloudfront server that would include it's IP address in the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does it always use the first IP first

Most modern DNS resolvers and authoritative servers will randomise the order of the IP addresses -- more precisely, the set of A records for a given domain name.

So, "first IP" really isn't deterministic at all.

> and use the others only if it fails?

Obviously this is very browser-dependent. [*Most* modern browsers do handle it](http://www.nber.org/sys-admin/dns-failover.html) by retrying the other IPs. I wouldn't count on it though.

> is there any way from within the browser that I can get these IP addresses as they are from the client users system?

From Chrome devtools network panel, you can see the address that the browser connected to in the "Remote Address" field of a request. However, I'm not aware of any way to access that from Javascript on a page.

> It's my understanding that they will get a different list of IPs based on their IP address.

Yes.

> is there any type of request that I could send to the cloudfront server that would include it's IP address in the response?

Not that I know of. However, you might be able to reverse engineer the `Via` or `X-Amz-Cf-Id` response header? At a cursory glance, both are unintelligible to me after hex or base64 decoding.

That said, there is a trick that you might be able to use, i.e. that you could setup a URL prefix in your distribution that forwards the requests to your server running PHP. You then point your users to a URL that would result in a request that gets forwarded to your PHP script. In your PHP script, examine the `X-Forwarded-For` header, which should include a Cloudfront IP.